# when will systemd consider my service/application has started

Tags: systemd, startup, c++

I'm writing an application and use `systemd` to auto start it as the 1st service. There is some other application which also runs as a service and I want the 2nd service start after my 1st service.

```
[Unit]
Description=2nd service
After=1st.service
```

The question is, when and how systemd will consider my 1st service as started so it will continue to start my 2nd service.

More specifically, will my `main()` in 1st applicaiton block systemd?

```
int main()
{
    ..block 1 sec and wait for something
}
```

I have a feeling that I have some mistake in some basic concepts, but how to clearly understand this behavior? In my case of the 1st application, which part of my code will impact the startup time which affects `systemd`?